# New pandas column based on whether functions are called

Tags: python, pandas

I have a class which calls functions depending on whether initial keywords are true or false. The intention is to be able to control how I create a new column in dataframe `df`. An abridged version of the class and functions is as follows:

```
class DFSetter:

    def __init__(self, justify=True, caps=True, table=True):
        if justify:
            self.set_justify()
        if caps:
            self.set_all_caps()
        if self.table:
            self.set_table()

    def set_justify(self):
        self.justify = (self.df['jc'] != self.df['jc'].shift())

    def set_all_caps(self):
        self.all_caps = ((self.df['caps']==True) & (self.df['cap_diffs']>5))

    def set_table(self):
        self.table = ((self.df['table'] == True) & (self.df['table'].shift() == False))
```

Suppose I want to make a new column, `row_break` in this dataframe which will set to `True` if any of the conditions are met. How could I create this new column if the call to one of the functions is switched off by initialising it as `False`?

This is currently how I'm doing it with everything set to True:

`self.df['row_break'] = (self.justify | self.all_caps | self.table | pStyle)`

*** UPDATE WITH ANSWER ***

Initialise with additional `self.switches={}` and add `self.switches.update({'item':self.item})` to each function.

Create a new dataframe from the self.switches dictionary: `self.switches_df=(self.switches)`

Set 'row_break' column on main self.df dataframe by seeing if any of the columns are True: `self.df['row_break'] = (self.switches_df.any(axis='columns')`

i.e

```
class DFSetter:

    def __init__(self, justify=True, caps=True, table=True):

        self.switches={}
        if justify:
            self.set_justify()
        if caps:
            self.set_all_caps()
        if self.table:
            self.set_table()

    def set_justify(self):
        self.justify = (self.df['jc'] != self.df['jc'].shift())
        self.switches.update({'justify':self.justify})

    def set_all_caps(self):
        self.all_caps = ((self.df['caps']==True) & (self.df['cap_diffs']>5))
        self.switches.update({'caps':self.all_caps})

    def set_table(self):
        self.table = ((self.df['table'] == True) & (self.df['table'].shift() == False))
        self.switches.update({'table':self.table})

    def set_row_break(self):
        switches_df = pd.DataFrame(self.switches)
        self.df['row_break'] = switches_df.any(axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize the new column to false and then update it for each of the conditions that are set to true.

I'm assuming here that the dataframe is one of the inputs to the class (since you use `self.df`).

```
class DFSetter:

    def __init__(self, df, justify=True, caps=True, table=True):

        self.df = df
        self.df['row_break'] = False

        if justify:
            self.set_justify()
        if caps:
            self.set_all_caps()
        if self.table:
            self.set_table()

    def set_justify(self):
        self.justify = (self.df['jc'] != self.df['jc'].shift())
        self.df['row_break'] = self.df['row_break'] | self.justify

    def set_all_caps(self):
        self.all_caps = ((self.df['caps']==True) & (self.df['cap_diffs']>5))
        self.df['row_break'] = self.df['row_break'] | self.all_caps 

    def set_table(self):
        self.table = ((self.df['table'] == True) & (self.df['table'].shift() == False))
        self.df['row_break'] = self.df['row_break'] | self.table
```

Alternativly, keeping to the same idea, the `self.df['row_break']` assignments could be done inside each if statement. In this way, the `set_`-methods would be kept cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @Shaido - I've updated my question with my answer but have marked yours as correct as I think it's cleaner